# Comparing two variables in an xsl:if statement always yields true, but data suggest otherwise

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, if-statement, compare

I want to do the following Transformation:
A exemplaric XML input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <Object ObjectID="123" <!-- Some other attributes -->/>
    <Object ObjectID="456" <!-- Some other attributes -->/>
    <ListItem ReferenceToObject="123" Name="ABC"/>
    <ListItem ReferenceToObject="456" Name="DEF"/>
    <ListItem ReferenceToObject="456" Name="GHI"/>
</Data>
```

The stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Data>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Data/Object">
            <Object>
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ObjectID"/>
                </ID>
                <List>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/Data/ListItem">
                        <xsl:variable name="ObjectID" select="/Data/Object/@ObjectID"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="ReferenceToObject" select="@ReferenceToObject"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$ObjectID=$ReferenceToObject">
                            <ReferenceToObject>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$ReferenceToObject"/>
                            </ReferenceToObject>
                            <Name>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                            </Name>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </List>
            </Object>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <Object>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <List>
            <ListItem>
                <ReferenceToObject>123</ReferenceToObject>
                <Name>ABC</Name>
            </ListItem>
        </List>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <ID>456</ID>
        <List>
            <ListItem>
                <ReferenceToObject>456</ReferenceToObject>
                <Name>DEF</Name>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem>
                <ReferenceToObject>456</ReferenceToObject>
                <Name>GHI</Name>
            </ListItem>
        </List>
    </Object>
</Data>
```

The output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <Object>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <List>
            <ListItem>
                <ReferenceToObject>123</ReferenceToObject>
                <Name>ABC</Name>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem>
                <ReferenceToObject>456</ReferenceToObject>
                <Name>DEF</Name>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem>
                <ReferenceToObject>456</ReferenceToObject>
                <Name>GHI</Name>
            </ListItem>
        </List>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <ID>456</ID>
        <List>
            <ListItem>
                <ReferenceToObject>123</ReferenceToObject>
                <Name>ABC</Name>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem>
                <ReferenceToObject>456</ReferenceToObject>
                <Name>DEF</Name>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem>
                <ReferenceToObject>456</ReferenceToObject>
                <Name>GHI</Name>
            </ListItem>
        </List>
    </Object>
</Data>
```

The thing I don't get is why does every Object have every ListItem? I want one Object to contain just those ListItems whose `<ReferenceToObject>` attributes match the Objects `<ObjectID>` attribute. Therefore the if-statement in my stylesheet. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example, including a sample XML input and the expected output.

Comment: I can't readily think of a scenario where your code would fail, so we really need to have your input XML that can be used with your stylesheet. Please provide a [mcve]. See also guidelines: [ask].

Comment: Please see my edited question and let me know if the samples are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is here:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Data/ListItem">
    <xsl:variable name="ObjectID" select="/Data/Object/@ObjectID"/>
```

You are in the context of a `ListItem` and you are selecting **all** `ObjectID`s in the entire document, starting from the root. When you later compare the current `ListItem`'s `ReferenceToObject` to the values stored in the `$ObjectID` variable, one of the values stored there will match, no matter which `Object` or `ListItem` is current.

You should have declared the variable while still in the context of `Object` and populated it with the value of current `Object` only:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Data>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Data/Object">
             <xsl:variable name="ObjectID" select="@ObjectID"/>        
            <Object>
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ObjectID"/>
                </ID>
                <List>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/Data/ListItem">
                        <xsl:variable name="ReferenceToObject" select="@ReferenceToObject"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$ObjectID=$ReferenceToObject">
                            <ReferenceToObject>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$ReferenceToObject"/>                                
                            </ReferenceToObject>
                            <Name>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                            </Name>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </List>
            </Object>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that a better way to resolve cross-references is to use a key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-obj" match="ListItem" use="@ReferenceToObject" />

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <Data>
        <xsl:for-each select="Object">
            <Object>
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ObjectID"/>
                </ID>
                <List>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('item-by-obj', @ObjectID)">
                        <ReferenceToObject>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@ReferenceToObject"/>                                
                        </ReferenceToObject>
                        <Name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                        </Name>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </List>
            </Object>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Spot on, as always :). It really **does help** when an OP shares their code ;).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you very much! I like the `<xsl:key>` approach a lot and it works perfectly! Your explanation also helped me to finally understand what was going wrong and why :)
@Abel I promise to do better next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Completly re-written due to own wrong assumption and edit question.

The important point is: You have to select just those `ListItems` you want to process. I.e., the `ListItems` with `@ReferenceToObject` pointing to the Object in question.

The best way to do that, is with an XPath condition right there in the for-each-loop:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Data>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Data/Object">
            <Object>
                <xsl:variable name="ObjectID" select="string(@ObjectID)"/>
                <ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ObjectID"/>
                </ID>
                <List>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/Data/ListItem[@ReferenceToObject=$ObjectID]">
                      <ReferenceToObject>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@ReferenceToObject"/>
                            </ReferenceToObject>
                            <Name>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                            </Name>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </List>
            </Object>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your mistake was in the path expresion in `<xsl:variable name="ObjectID" select="/Data/Object/@ObjectID"/>` Here, you stored **every** ObjectID of every Object - and not just that of the context node. Also this variable declaration was at the wrong position. It should be inside the first loop, but not inside the second. Only this way, the context node would be Object and not ListItem.

Comment: Clear explanation, except that in this case it doesn't matter. The equality operator already works on values of the nodes (perhaps you confused it with the identity operator of xpath 2.0?). More likely, the OP made a wrong selection.

Comment: Your absolutely right. I had a similiar problem with attributes in another context and thus may have confused the processor's behaviour.

Comment: @cis Thanks for your explanation, it really helped to understand my mistake! However, I find Michaels approach slightly better because it's cleaner and more straightforward to me. +1 for the explanation though.